# CosmosDB is not returning all results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to run a query to find all documents with duplicated e-mails.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT c.Email, COUNT(1) as cnt FROM c GROUP BY c.Email) a WHERE a.cnt > 1
```

When I run it in Data Explorer in Azure Portal it finds 4 results, but it's not a complete list of duplicated emails, because I already know one email that is duplicated and when the query is narrowed (where email = 'x') it is returned and there are about 70 duplicated emails in the collection.

Currently, throughput is set to autoscale with 6000 Max RU/s, the collection has about 4kk of documents. When running the query I observe an increased count of 429s responses on this collection.

Query Statistics shows that all documents are retrieved from the collection, but output is only 4 (should be around 70).
[image: Query Statistics]

Query used 277324 RUs and took 71 seconds which gives 3905 RU/s in average, so it shouldn't be throttled.

Why cosmos returns only limited results for this query?
What can I do to get all duplicates?

Comment: what is the storage size?

Comment: Seems like you are missing some indexes, the amount of RU is very high: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-query-performance#queries-where-retrieved-document-count-exceeds-output-document-count

Comment: We're running into exactly the same problem, did you find a solution for it?